# Why could a browser not caching a resource with Cache-Control HTTP headers?

Tags: http, caching, header, http-headers

I've read all the caching documentation for HTTP, and this are the headers for my file:
Edit: I am now using amazon S3 to see if it helps and still the same problem! Here go the request and the response> What am I missing? Even thought the response asks for the browser to cache the file, it doesn't! I've checked the Google Chrome cache and the file is not there.

```
Request URL:https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/combo-combat-release/WebPlayer.unity3d
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

**Request Headers**
GET /combo-combat-release/WebPlayer.unity3d HTTP/1.1
Host: s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: es,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

**Response Headers**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: xu/RKgR4Xt6G3jQ1qkdO5rzd4TlngDYYERZ+bbGlalitJFMDjAgiLAoP4GXhmkeo
x-amz-request-id: 6A9389D16407D28D
Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 22:42:26 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public, must-revalidate
Last-Modified: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 22:29:55 GMT
ETag: "0f8d22257da9fcae61f21fd30b7a1fd4"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 39222189
Server: AmazonS3
```

But the browser doesn't cache the file. Each time, the request is sent and all the data transferred from scratch (200 OK instead of 304). :(

File size is 37.4 MB

Any tip on what could be wrong?

Thanks,
Manuel

Comment: Maybe because "Expires" and "Last-Modified" are invalid dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try HTTP 1.1 instead of 1.0.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html states:

*Note that HTTP/1.0 caches might not implement Cache-Control and
might only implement Pragma: no-cache*

Comment: Wow... I didn't even notice it was HTTP/1.0, thanks! I changed it and it's still not working though... :( Will edit with new data, I'm trying with amazon S3 now and still not working! :O

Comment: I'm out of +1's, will do it tomorrow, sorry!

Comment: The protocol version on the wire basically has zero impact on caching.